# D3.js line chart not visible for same data points overlapped

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a line chart [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJYlB.png).But it is getting overlapped with the other line which are having the same set of data points.

Any solution to handle this situation.

Comment: This is a lot of code... could you provide more information, specifically the line number you're referring to in your question?

Comment: @Wade the line number is  1439 where on click of legend the code to animate the bars is written